# Mysql access remotely

Tags: mysql, database, django, python-2.7, mysql-python

I have deployed one django application on live IP adress Backend is Mysql running on the same IP.

There is pythoncard(GUI) application installed on some another DNS/Gateway.

I am getting **2003 can't connect mysql server on** .**.**.242* while executing.

**Grant all** and everything done but it is raising the same error. How do I connect to that host through internet or static IP.

HOw to resolve it? Mysql level or application level

Thank you

This is my.conf

```
[client]

port=3306

[mysql]

default-character-set=latin1

[mysqld]

# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on

port=3306

bind-address = 110.243.143.*** # SERVER IPADDRESS

# skip-networking

#Path to installation directory. All paths are usually resolved relative to this.
basedir="C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure MySQL is listening on your public IP. You can set this in `my.cnf`. The property you are looking for is [`bind-address`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address).
2. Next, make sure your user is authorized to connect from a remote IP. You can adjust the permissions using the [`GRANT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html) statement.

Comment: Thank your valuable answer at the valuable time. Which adress i need to keep there, My LiveIP or 127.0.0.1, and how do I check my MYSQL is listing or not, Please don't mind. I was totally confused because it is working in intranet environment

Comment: In step 1, its the public address of your mysql server, and in step 2 you can put the static ip of your client, or simply `%` for "all ips".

Comment: I followed the step1, in [mysqld] section under port = 3306, I have mentioned the IP ***.***.***.** you specified, but it is giving me the 2003 error, MYSQL is not listining?

Comment: Update the question with your `my.cnf`

Comment: Thank you Burhan Khalid for your reply. Mysql is working, I am getting the error because of the FireWall issue, I added one rule to it. It is working fine'

Comment: Thank you Khalid, It is working fine after following your steps. Problem is Firewall. I have added a Rule to that PORT. It is resolved now